# How do I upgrade my old Asp.Net Identity database to the current one?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-identity

How do I upgrade my current Asp.Net Identity SQL database to the current one. My aspnet_Users table has the following fields (ApplicationId, UserId, UserName, LoweredUserName, MobileAlias, IsAnonymous, LastActivityDate). I assume the new structure has additional fields like email confirmation e.t.c below is my list of tables.

Comment: If you are talking about versions, please put the version numbers in your question

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the current version of **ASP.Net Identity** is version 3. But the specific distinction I am making between the one I have and the new one is the number and names of fields in the aspnet_Users table. Mine, which is old has the fields given above, while the new one has extra fields like `id, Email, EmailCOnfirmed, PasswordHash, SecurityStamp, PhoneNumber, TwoFactorEnabled, LockoutEndDate` etc.